# I want to add a bouding box around the user when his full body is visible to the webcam in react

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

import * as posenet from '@tensorflow-models/posenet';

const WebcamWithSegmentation = () => {

  const webcamRef = useRef(null);

  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const netRef = useRef(null);

  const drawBoundingBox = (ctx, box) => {

    if (!box) {

      return;

    }

    console.log('Drawing bounding box:', box);

    

    // Ensure non-negative starting point

  const startX = Math.max(0, box.x);

  const startY = Math.max(0, box.y);

  // Calculate adjusted width and height

  const adjustedWidth = box.width - Math.max(0, -box.x);

  const adjustedHeight = box.height - Math.max(0, -box.y);

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

  ctx.lineWidth = 4;

  ctx.strokeRect(startX, startY, adjustedWidth, adjustedHeight);

  };

  const getBoundingBox = (keypoints,minScore = 0.5) => {

    const validKeypoints = keypoints.filter(point => point.score > minScore);

    if (validKeypoints.length === 0) {

      return null; // No keypoints with sufficient score

    }

    const minX = Math.min(...validKeypoints.map(point => point.position.x));

    const minY = Math.min(...validKeypoints.map(point => point.position.y));

    const maxX = Math.max(...validKeypoints.map(point => point.position.x));

    const maxY = Math.max(...validKeypoints.map(point => point.position.y));

    return {

      x: minX,

      y: minY,

      width: maxX - minX,

      height: maxY - minY,

    };

  };

  const drawPoints = (ctx, keypoints, minScore) => {

    keypoints.forEach(keypoint => {

      if (keypoint.score >= minScore) {

        const { x, y } = keypoint.position;

        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

        ctx.fill();

      }

    });

  };

  useEffect(() => {

    const canvas = canvasRef.current;

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let net;

    const loadPoseNet = async () => {

      try {

        await tf.setBackend('webgl');

        net = await posenet.load();

        console.log('PoseNet loaded successfully');

        netRef.current = net;

        setLoading(false);

      } catch (error) {

        console.error('Error loading PoseNet:', error);

        setError(`Error l

Loading PoseNet: ${error.message}`);

        setLoading(false);

      }

    };

    const setupWebcam = async () => {

      try {

        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });

        const video = webcamRef.current;

        video.srcObject = stream;

        return new Promise((resolve) => {

          video.onloadedmetadata = () => {

            resolve(video);

          };

        });

      } catch (error) {

        console.error('Error accessing webcam:', error);

        setError(`Error accessing webcam: ${error.message}`);

        setLoading(false);

        return null;

      }

    };

    const drawWebcam = () => {

      const video = webcamRef.current;

      const net = netRef.current;

      if (!video || !video.videoWidth || !video.videoHeight || !net) {

        return;

      }

      const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;

      console.log('Video Dimensions:', videoWidth, videoHeight);

      if (canvas.width !== videoWidth || canvas.height !== videoHeight) {

        canvas.width = videoWidth;

        canvas.height = videoHeight;

      }

      

      context.clearRect(0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);

      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);

      net.estimateSinglePose(video, { flipHorizontal: false })

        .then(pose => {

         /* pose.keypoints.forEach(part => {

            console.log(`${part.part} score: ${part.score}`);

          });*/

          const isFullBodyVisible =

            pose.keypoints.find(part => part.part === 'leftAnkle').score >= 0.5 &&

            pose.keypoints.find(part => part.part === 'rightAnkle').score >= 0.5 &&

            pose.keypoints.find(part => part.part === 'leftShoulder').score >= 0.5 &&

            pose.keypoints.find(part => part.part === 'rightShoulder').score >= 0.5;

          if (isFullBodyVisible) {

            const boundingBox = getBoundingBox(pose.keypoints);

            console.log('Bounding Box:', boundingBox);

            drawBoundingBox(context, boundingBox);

          }

          drawPoints(context, pose.keypoints, 0.5);

        })

        .finally(() => {

          requestAnimationFrame(drawWebcam);

        });

    };

    const init = async () => {

      const video = await setupWebcam();

      if (!video) {

        return;

      }

      await loadPoseNet();

      video.play();

      requestAnimationFrame(drawWebcam);

    };

    init();

    return () => {

      // Cleanup when the component is unmounted

      if (webcamRef.current) {

        const video = webcamRef.current;

        if (video.srcObject) {

          const stream = video.srcObject;

          const tracks = stream.getTracks();

          tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());

        }

      }

      if (netRef.current) {

        1. tf.dispose([netRef.current]);

      }

    };

  }, []);

  return (

    <div>

      {loading && <p>Loading PoseNet...</p>}

      {error && <p>{error}</p>}

      <video ref={webcamRef} autoPlay width={640} height={480} />

      <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0 }} />

    </div>

  );

};

export default WebcamWithSegmentation;
```

This is the code but the bounding box does not appear at all. How to change this code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While your code appears to be mainly accurate, there may be a problem with the way the locations of the key points are calculated or the criteria used to determine if the entire body is shown.

replace the function `drawWebcam` and also, check if all necessary key points have a score above the threshold

```
const drawWebcam = () => {
  const video = webcamRef.current;
  const net = netRef.current;

  if (!video || !video.videoWidth || !video.videoHeight || !net) {
    return;
  }

  const { videoWidth, videoHeight } = video;

  if (canvas.width !== videoWidth || canvas.height !== videoHeight) {
    canvas.width = videoWidth;
    canvas.height = videoHeight;
  }

  context.clearRect(0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, videoWidth, videoHeight);

  net.estimateSinglePose(video, { flipHorizontal: false })
    .then(pose => {
      const keypoints = pose.keypoints;
      const isFullBodyVisible = keypoints.every(part => part.score >= 0.5);

      if (isFullBodyVisible) {
        const boundingBox = getBoundingBox(keypoints);
        console.log('Bounding Box:', boundingBox);
        drawBoundingBox(context, boundingBox);
      }

      drawPoints(context, keypoints, 0.5);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(drawWebcam);
    });
};
```